# How was "Hodor" adapted in other languages?

Tags: dialogue, game-of-thrones, translation

**Spoilers for episode 5 of season 6 "The Door".**

At the end of the episode we got to see how Wylis became Hodor and why all he can say is "Hodor".

If you've watched the episode you know that

> "Hold the Door" became "Hodor",

But how was this shown in versions of the episode dubbed in other languages?

If the name of character is pronounced "Hodor" in other languages, then the revelation of the origins of his name would become meaningless, as for example:

> "Hold the Door" in French is "tiens la porte". It would be interesting to see how the dubbed version converts it into "Hodor".

Comment: Ugh spoiler. But great question. Are the foreign dubs released at the same time?

Comment: Haha XD funny question. What I did was downloaded the subtitles in french, In it **Hold the door! ** was **Qu'ils n'aillent pas au-dehors !** and in the end when he yells **HODOR!** in french it was **Pas au-dehors !**

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be answered properly. Do you expect an answer for one language? Five? Fifty?

Comment: Perhaps this should be a community wiki.

Comment: Exactly, as Chanandler Bong pointed out, you asked the question  **how was this shown in versions of the episode dubbed in other languages?**    So are you expecting the answers in different languages? As you can see all people can do is answer in a separate languages, it cant even be wrong answer also at the same time it wont be fully right answer too .  o.O   For this reason I am flagging this question

Comment: **I have turned this into a single Community Wiki answer for everyone to edit their individual answers into it as this is the only way to salvage this question *if* it is deemed an appropriate question in the first place.** So anyone trying to answer it, please do so by adding your answer into the existing answer.

Comment: Well, if anyone has a foreign-translation of the books, is Hodor's name still "Hodor" in the book?

Comment: @Tab Alleman Obviously it is as the origin of the name was unknown until now and is still unknown in the books. After it appears in _Winds of Winter_ new translations may start taking this into account though.

Comment: I have to say. This is ***exactly*** what community wiki was made for :-)

Comment: This question is being copied on lots of media (italian links) http://www.serialminds.com/2016/05/31/hold-the-door-doppiaggio-lingue/ http://leganerd.com/2016/06/01/hold-the-door-doppiaggio-nelle-varie-lingue/ unfortunately this second one does not cite the source.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Brazilian Portuguese

"Segure a porta" ("Hold the door") → "a por-" → "Hodor"

Czech

"Drž vrata! Honem!" ("Hold the gate! Quick!"), where the evolution to Hodor is quite a stretch…

Danish

"Hold døren!" (subtitles, literal translation, no attempt to preserve alliteration).

Finnish

"Pitele ovea!" (subtitles, literal translation, no attempt to preserve alliteration).

French

As [pradyot commented](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53408/how-was-hodor-adapted-in-other-languages#comment84502_53408) "Qu'ils n'aillent pas au-dehors!" becomes "Pas au-dehors!" and then "Hodor".

German

"Halt das Tor!" whereas *Tor* is better translates to *gate* than to *door*. This actually works well for "Hodor".

Greek

"Κράτα την πόρτα!". It sounds nothing like Hodor, so from one point on they used greek letters to write "Hold The Door" (Χολντ δε ντορ) which eventually became "Χόντορ". This is a common practice in Greek and it's called Greekglish.

Hungarian

The meaning was changed "Holtodig óvd!" ("Defend him till your death!"), this phrase can be heard only once, the phrase Hodor and Meera repeats is "Óvd jól" (guard it well). The sound for both works more or less: Holt-óv → Ho-tó → Hodor, and "óvd jól" at least has the right vowels.

Italian

First shown in English with Italian subtitles (literal), then in Italian with integral translation after one week. Translators decided for a little addition to maintain the original meaning and then make the "Hodor" works: "Blocca la porta, trova un modo!" (Hold the door, find a way!) → trova un modo → rov...odo.. → hodor

Japanese

"ホーダー" [Ho-da-] which is a transliteration of "Hodor", coming from the English "Hold the Door". Interestingly in Japanese, door is pronounced ドア (doa) which if transliterated as such would make the name a lot closer to the English pronunciation. In Japanese, "hold the door" would be ドアを持って (doa wo motte) which would have more chance of making his name something like ドアモ (Doamo) in a purely Japanese version.

Norwegian

"Hold døra!" (subtitles, literal translation, no attempt to preserve alliteration).

Russian

"затвори ход" ("close the passage") which transitions to "hodor" in quite a strange and unusual way. The word "ход" is closer to "hatchway" than "door".

Serbian

"Hodi, dobro drži vrata!" ("Come on, hold the door tightly...")... then "Hodi... dobro..." ("Come on... tightly..."), then just  "hodor...". Alliteration was preserved as much as possible, while it's obviously not the best way to say it.

Spanish (Latin America)

"Déjalo cerrado". A strange way to say "keep it closed", also needs some imagination to make it work.

Spanish

"Aguanta el portón" (Not Ocluye el corredor) in Spain the word door "puerta" was replaced with main/front door "portón" in order for an easier transition to Hodor.

Swedish

"Håll dörren!" (subtitles, literal translation, no attempt to preserve alliteration).

Turkish

"Orada dur!" which means "Stand there!". It is not dubbed but subtitled. It evolves as: "Orada dur! → Ordadur! → Hordor! → Hodor!".

Comment: Here in Portugal Game of Thrones is aired by Syfy one day after the American release, subbed of course. When that scene happened, the subtitles were like this: >!Hold the door! (Segura a porta!) They wrote exactly what he said, in English. This is what you would expect if the translation is made by a professional team I guess.

Comment: I am sure, none of teh India language can do it.

Comment: In Latvian language "Hold the door" translates as "Turi durvis". It kind of works. "Turi durvis" > "Tur durvs" > "Tur durv" > "Tudurv" > "Tudur" > "Udur" > "Odor" > "Hodor".

Comment: As a french, Pas au-dehors is spot on the translation, even better than Hold the door.

Comment: An Italian subtitle read "Orda", translation of "Horde", totally losing the meaning but keeping the sound.

Comment: You can also have a look at this gallery: http://imgur.com/gallery/T6GPX

Comment: There are several translations to Russian - the one you mentioned it not the best one (to my mind) in comparison with: Стой у входа > У входа > Хода > Ходор (means Stay next to the entrance > Next to the entrance> Path > Hodor)