# How many references to famous Holmeses are there in Sherlock?

Tags: sherlock, reference

In Sherlock's series four finale "*The Final Problem*" there are multiple references to Basil Rathbone and possibly other famous Holmeses.

In [this Buzzfeed article](https://www.buzzfeed.com/scottybryan/that-episode-was-like-drinking-ten-cups-of-coffee?utm_term=.kjNVp4pxX#.imgQObOBJ) is the following quote from one of the show's creators:

> "That is him becoming the Sherlock Holmes of Basil Rathbone and Jeremy Brett."

How many and which references to other famous *Holmeses* are there in the episode?

Comment: Why the down-vote? It's more constructive to explain.

Comment: To the close-voters: I don't think this is *too broad*, in fact this is similar to http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/53408/16465 in that case a community wiki did the job, why not here?

Answer (score 4):

Please add to this list with any references you can find.

#### Basil Rathbone

1. At 01:24:57 there is a book lying on its side that reads

   > Rathbone Neville "The Eight"

   [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=neville+rathbone+the+eight&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari) shows this isn't a real book and is certainly a reference to Basil Rathbone. 
   [image: Rathbone image]
2. At the end of the episode the lead characters end in mid-air in between signs saying "*RATHBONE PLACE*". The place is real but the scene was [not shot there](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rathbone_Place). [image: Rathbone Place sign]