# Is Voldemort called "Tom Elvis Riddle" in the French versions of Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

A friend told me that in the French versions of Harry Potter, they had to make Voldemort's middle name "Elvis". They said that they did this in order to make the "Tom Marvolo Riddle" to "I am Lord Voldemort" anagram to work.

Now I don't know French that well, but I thought this was too funny to be true.

Did this really happen, or is one of my friends lying to me? If it did happen, can anyone show how?

---

NB: This is a *movies* and TV site so answers should be about the movies, not the books. This was correctly raised [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2742/48930).

Comment: HP Wikia has a full list of such changes. Can't fetch it now because I'm boycotting HP Wikia, but the list is hilarious!

Comment: I always thought it was odd how his name anagram included 'I am' in it. Without including those two words translation issues aren't really an issue in my opinion. Though, I'm betting 'I am' came as a result of wanting to have 'Riddle' as the last name, as a foreshadowing that his name is actually some sort of Riddle.

Comment: In the Russian translation, Voldemort is changed to Volan-de-mort, so your question definitely sounds plausible.

Comment: @Thunderforge why change the title? I like the pun. What's wrong with it as it is?

Comment: @ThisGuy The original title wasn't a question and didn't really describe the contents of it (virtually every other question tagged with [tag:harry-potter] has a question in the title). It was also a Hot Network Question and so I felt it should be changed to showcase a higher standard of quality for this site. It was never a pun anyway (it wasn't two words that sound the same), but I did keep the name in the title.

Comment: It's worth seeing the whole video by Vox, but if you start [here](https://youtu.be/UdbOhvjIJxI?t=3m38s), you'll see that they discuss the French translation of the name.

Comment: Related meta discussion: [Would this question be about the books, and therefore off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2742/49)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson really? Also the currently highest voted answer doesn't mention the books and I'm accepting it in a bit. In addition, to me personally, the "translators" imply talking/filmography. I don't know about you but...

Comment: I, for one, can't wait to see 'Hodor' in other languages.

Comment: @Shane French:"Hodor" Spanish:"Hodor" German:"Hodor" any language:"Hodor"

Comment: @ThisGuy Well, feel free to share your insights on the respective meta discussion. I just dropped it here for reference purposes.

Comment: @Shane [How was “Hodor” adapted in other languages](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/53408/49)

Comment: *"to me personally, the "translators" imply talking/filmography"* - That...is a stretch though. You won't believe how the guys translating books are called. ;-)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's true that the second name is Elvis, but the last name is also different in French. To make the anagram work there are many different versions of the name in other languages.

> In other languages, translators replaced the entire name to preserve the anagram. In French, Riddle's full name becomes Tom Elvis Jedusor (...) which forms an anagram for "Je suis Voldemort" ("I am Voldemort").

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_in_translation)

Comment: So… Marvolo Gaunt is Elvis Gaunt in France?!

Comment: he is actually elvis marvolo gaunt

Comment: To give another example of such an anagram where it's even more different: In Dutch, he's called Marten Asmodom Vilijn, which swaps around for "Mijn naam is Voldemort".

Comment: @Nzall any relation to [Asmodean](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Asmodean)?

Comment: Tom Rojvol R**a**ddle in Czech, which swaps around for "Já, Lord Voldemort"...

Comment: @muru you sir are awarded +1 interwebs for mentioning *The Wheel of Time.*

Comment: @muru: It seems probable both names ultimately derive from Asmodeus, with appropriate sinister connotations. ("Vilijn", in Dutch, has the same sound as "vilein" - "vile", "villainous"). Unlike "Tom Marvolo Riddle", "Marten Asmodom Vilijn" is a name to run away from really fast. (Obligatory link to TVTropes deliberately omitted.)

Answer (score 31):

Lot of names were actually changed in the French translation of the books. It is the case of Tom Marvolo Riddle which is translated to *"Tom Elvis Jedusor"* to make the anagram works, but Snape (*Rogue* in French), Mad-Eye Moody (*Maugrey Fol Œil* in French), Hogwarts (*Poudlard* in French), Muggle (*Moldu* in French), Crucio (*Endoloris* in French) and so many other names or spells have been changed by the French translator in order to preserve the puns.

Note that the French "Jedusor = Jeu du sort" means "game of spell" or "game of fate" as you want, which does not exactly mean riddle but which keeps the idea of playing with words.

Comment: I wonder why the French publishers just didn't have Harry go to Beaubatons. ;)

Comment: @krillgar isn't it exclusively a school for girls? are they going to also rename the main character to Harriet Potter?

Comment: @immibis in the movies Beauxbatons is indeed a girl school but (at least only girls are shown) but this is not the case in the books

Comment: Are "Snape" and "Muggle" puns?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, they do. If not, the anagram doesn't work. In spanish, for example, his name is "Tom Sorvolo Ryddle" (Soy Lord Voldemort). [Here's the spanish version](http://es.harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tom_Ryddle).